# How to make a regexp to match strings with random dots between patterns?

Tags: regex, go

I'd like to compare a string with a slice of patterns and see if there is any permutation of patterns with dots in between:

The functin looks like this:

```
patterns := []string{"cat", "fish", "dog"}
func HasBadPattern(word string, patterns []string) bool {       
    for _, p := range patterns {
        myRegex, err := regexp.Compile(p)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        //Don't know how to perpare the wordToCompile ?
        matched := myRegex.FindString(wordToCompile)
        if len(matched) > 0 {
            return true
            break
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The result should be like this:

```
HasBadPattern("c.at", patterns) //true
HasBadPattern("c.a.t", patterns) //true
HasBadPattern("c.a..t", patterns) //true
HasBadPattern("fis.h", patterns) //true
HasBadPattern("catfish", patterns) //false
HasBadPattern("here is the cat.", patterns) //false
HasBadPattern("cat is on the mat.", patterns) //false
HasBadPattern("cat.fish", patterns) //false
```

My problem is how to prepare the `word` to be compiled for dots in between charachters, without creating false positives.

[Here is the playground scaffolding](https://play.golang.org/p/0vuSC8Rj293)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you basically want to insert `\.*` (zero or more periods) between the characters of your string. For example, `"c.at"`, `"c.a.t"` and `"c.a..t"` are all matched by the expression `^\.*c\.*a\.*t\.*$`.

This could be done using a function like (not the most efficient...):

```
func randomDots(word string) string {
    dots := "\\.*"
    expression := fmt.Sprintf("^%s", dots)

    for i := range word {
        expression += fmt.Sprintf("%c%s", word[i], dots)
    }
    expression += "$"
    return expression
}
```

Then you could just change `HasBadPattern` to:

```
func HasBadPattern(word string, patterns []string) bool {
    for _, p := range patterns {
        expression := randomDots(p)
        myRegex, _ := regexp.Compile(expression)
        matched := myRegex.FindString(word)
        if len(matched) > 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: @josebit The link shows code with your original `HasBadPattern` function extant. Please note I changed it; try replace the function with the code above. `randomDots` won't do anything unless it's called... Is [this](https://play.golang.org/p/7HS6zi-Ky_h) what you're after?

Comment: Well, aadding `.*`between characters opens door to many false positives becaue anything can go between `^\.*c\.*a\.*.\.*t\.*$`  like `something. can. add here`

Comment: You're wrong. `.*` matches zero or more of any character; `\.*` matches zero or more periods.

Comment: Right. Any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: The reason `randomDots` is not that efficient is that strings are slices in Go, which means every time we append to a string, a new array is allocated in the background. I don't think it's a big deal, though: if you're going to be calling `HasBadPattern` often, it would be better to store the patterns rather than the base words in `patterns`; that way, the patterns wouldn't need to be generated each time `HasBadPattern` is called.

Answer (score -2):

to match the cat case. try following regex.

your regex implementation might be a different in golang, I tested it with https://regexr.com and it works fine.  quoting the dot special character may also be a good idea.

c[.]{0,}[.]a[.]{0,}[.]?t

which passes your test case.

If you want to match fish or other words then you'll to create another regex dynamically, on the fly.

Have Fun!

Comment: Well, that's the problem. There are several douzens of words and it is not practical to  build regexp like `c[.]{0,}[.]a[.]{0,}[.]?t` for any individual of them.

Comment: it should be trivial to convert a string like DOG to  d[.]{0,}[.]o[.]{0,}[.]?g ... as you matching for specific words your going to have to build the regex dynamically. Unless you use a more generic match of [a-z] , but you'll start matching a..b..z. So i can't see how you can do this without generating a dynamic regex on the fly.

Comment: Using `word := "c[.]{0,}[.]a[.]{0,}[.]?t"` I still get  `c.a..t  false` . So the regexp seems to be faulty.

Comment: you regex implementation might be a different, I tested it with https://regexr.com/ and it works fine. try quoting the dot special character too. c[\.]{0,}[\.]a[\.]{0,}[\.]?t  good luck.

Comment: looks like someone has do a full implementation that creates a dynamic regex for you!!! lucky you!